# Why this controller is not working in code-igniter version 3.0.1?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

I kept the file name as Users.php, still its not working.

Comment: My default controller is "welcome" only....I am using this in my browser http://localhost/code-ignitor/index.php/users.....and getting 404 error.

Comment: Read first [http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

Answer (score 1):

Please Consider about **Codeigniter naming conversion**.

and

in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

place `.htaccess` outside application folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

and

in `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "users";//default controller name
```

and in URL

```
http://localhost/<path to file>/project_name/users
```

> ***Note :*** **You cant access URL with any file extensions like `.php` or `.html`.**

Answer (score 0):

start contract function in your class

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

And run the url as `example.com/index.php/users/`

Comment: Tried...still not working...I think its some version problem ....may be the syntax to save the file name

Comment: This thing is very irritating in codeignitor. I have tried so many things still not able to remove this minor bug

Comment: what is your `base_url()` in `config.php` file?

Comment: @PulkitMalhotra, CodeIgniter is one of the most widely used Frameworks. And the simplest one for beginners. Please do some research and you will know.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out:

-> app/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/homePage';
```

-> app/controllers/Pages.php (Note the capital P on the file)

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends MY_Controller {//Note the capital Class name
    public function homePage()
    {
        $this->load->view("pages/homepage.php");
    }
}
```

Also to get rid of the index.php do the following :

-> app/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Create a file called ".htaccess" outside the app folder and put the following code in it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This HTaccess is from another PHP framework called Laravel, it seems to be working better than the standard CI's HTaccess that they provide on their website.

I hope this helps you out.